# How to download .csv or .xls data from Stack Overflow trends?

Tags: support, meta, data-explorer, trends

Is it possible to download .csv or .xls files of the data from the [Stack Overflow Trends tool](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=r%2Cstatistics)? Or is there a particular query I need to use to do this in the Data Explorer tool?

I'm particularly interested in acquiring the data used in [this chart](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/06/incredible-growth-python/):

[image]